# MVVMCross Unified Announcement

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am new to MVVMCross and ~6 Mos with Xamarin…
From the Xamarin blog post today : http://blog.xamarin.com/unified-api-and-64-bit-support-complete/
What does that mean as far as MVVMCross is concerned?
I am using MVVMCross 3.2.2  Xamarin Forms (Android, iOS, WinPhone 8.0) and added a Universal Project for Windows Store/Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

MVVMCross and all of the plugins will have to be updated to support the new Unified API that is currently in Alpha. Once they release this you can migrate your iOS application over.

I know that Stuart and Thomasz have already been working on this though. Ideally, if you read through the post you should look to migrate around January 5th when it hits stable.